# XCode: changing string in Localizable.strings

Tags: ios, xcode, localizable.strings

I am new to XCode. I am trying to change a value of a string in Localizable.strings file.

from

"string key" = "old value"

To

"string key" = "new value"

I updated the file. rebuild the App. but still getting "old value".

Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project and the build folder.

In Xcode press:

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and press `Yes`.
*(cleans project)*

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and press `Yes`.
*(cleans build folder)*

Then try re-building and running.

#### Other things to check:

- Is the file included in correct targets?
  *(click on the file in Xcode and you'll find build targets in the Inspector view).*
- Is the actual string in the app localized? Is `NSLocalizedString()` macro used in the place where you expect the new string to be shown?

Comment: Didn't work!!! yes the file is included in the correct targets and NSLocalizedString() is used